# HBase Bulk Loading Error. What Wrong?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I tried to data bulk loading into hbase table like below and successed.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=/tmp/example_output -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:val1,cf1:val2,cf1:val3 so_table /user/uclab/smallbusiness/bulk3/
```

After doing this job, I performed like below.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /tmp/example_output so_table
```

But Some error occured recursively like below.

```
2015-10-12 01:52:42.835 DEBUG [LoadIncrementalHFiles-0]  
mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Goint to connect to server 
regiont=so_table,,1444580736986.3c5aa99d4ca4dcb509c8cfb26c2b223f., 
hostname=datanode83,60020,1444578166533, seqNum=2 for row with hfile 
group[{[B@5d37ce06,hdfs://namenode.uclab.com:8020/tmp/example_output/cf1/541f346
80be24932afa54c3fa14e4ad4}]
```

and

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException
(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): 
Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE,
inode="/tmp/example_output/cf1":uclab:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

How can I give write permission? and How can I solve this problem...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too faced similar kinda problem on **`Cloudera Quickstart VM`**.

Change the owner to **`“hbase”`** or **`HBase`** won’t have the permission to move the files. Run the following command:

**`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chown -R   hbase:hbase /tmp/example_output`**

Now run

**`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles /tmp/example_output so_table`**

Comment: After this I am getting  ** mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Bulk load operation did not find any files to load in directory /user/cloudera/workspace/mmm/output.  Does it contain files in subdirectories that correspond to column family names?
**                                                                                                                    The importtsv tool with bulk loading option created subdirectories in output folder. The subdirectories have same name as column names and those subdirectories contain the files. Whats wrong?